# double.ToString("G") but always include point?

Tags: c#, .net, formatting, double, tostring

Is there a formatting code which essentially assumes the "G" formatting specification but always ensures that the decimal point is shown?

For instance:

- 1 = "1.0"
- 123 = "123.0"
- 10000 = "1e+4"

Or will I just need to use something like the following:

```
string str = someDouble.ToString();
if (!str.Contains('.') && !str.Contains('e') && !string.Contains('E'))
    str += ".0";
```

Comment: @BradleyDotNET "F1" doesn't shorten long values by introducing the exponent notation. I guess I would be happy if I could force the decimal point even in those cases however, for instance 10000 = 1.0e+4.

Comment: If you always want a decimal point, why is 1e+4 acceptable?

Comment: @hvd I want to ensure that the value is clearly a float/double type value so that I can differentiate between integer values. Tbh I would be entirely happy with 1.0e+4 type values.